# react curly brace inside curly brace

Tags: reactjs

Hi I Try to have a list like this:

```
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", "apple"]}/>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", "microsoft"]}/>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", "google"]}/>
```

in place of apple microsoft and google I loop through links like that

```
var links = ["apple","microsoft","google"];
 const listItems = links.map((link) =>
      <li key={link}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", {link}]}/>
      </li>
```

but the problem is that I don't know how to get link inside {[{link}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the curly braces you are passing an object with a link property, remove the braces.

```
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", link]}/>
```